# Good way to create script supporting translations?

Tags: php, localization, translation, structure

I'm creating an open-source cms and was just wondering that which is the best way to add localizations? I already decided to have them in files similar to lang.en.php. I would assume arrays, but in which form?

```
$lang['xyz'] = "Text goes here!";
$lang['Text goes here!'] = "Translated text!";
```

Or should I create my custom parser and add localizations to a file, like this:

```
"Text goes here!" = "Translated text!";
```

And then just parse it.

What would you suggest? I tried to search but no results for me.

Martti Laine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=localization+php

Comment: Well thank you Peter, but I already tried that and didn't find a nice way for this. Don't misunderstand me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the [Gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) library for Desktop applications does something similar to your custom parser. [Gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) has a module in PHP, but I'm not sure if it's installed in most PHP installations by default.

Basically, you would write every string with it with a function name `tr("How are you?")`. Then create a function to translate it:

```
include('lang.es.php');
function tr($txt) {
   global $tr;
   if(array_key_exists($txt,$tr)) {
     return $tr($txt);
   }
   return $txt;
}
```

And in lang.es.php, have:

```
$tr = array();
$tr["How are you?"] = "¿Como Estas?";
```

You would probably want to do `printf(tr("How are you, %s?"), $name);` for variables, or proper nouns that should not be translated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Joomla way. Language files must be in ini extension:

```
FOO=translation
BAR=translation2
```

then you parse the file with parse_ini_file function and get the translation array:

```
$dictionary=parse_ini_file("english.ini");

    function translate($text)
    {
       global $dictionary;
       if(isset($dictionary[strtoupper($text)])) return $dictionary[strtoupper($text)];
       else return $text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as you think it is, do you really need hundreds of rows in an array in order to translate `I deleted 45 comments`, or `I deleted 192 comments`? etc.

It would be very helpful if you could call a translate function with: `translate('I deleted %d comments', $number);`

```
<?php
    $dict = parse_ini_file('lang.ini');

    function translate($text){
        global $dict;
        $args = func_get_args();
        if(isset($dict[$text])){
            // I am not sure how to convert %d in $args[.], maybe someone else could provide a regular expression for this.
        } else {
            return $text;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How will you manage plural form ?

Some languages have very tricky plural rules : [example here](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/Plural-forms.html)

> In Polish we use e.g. plik (file) this
> way:
>
> ```
>       1 plik
>       2,3,4 pliki
>       5-21 pliko'w
>       22-24 pliki
>       25-31 pliko'w
> ```

For this reason, I suggest you to use gettext because everything has been done for you.

Comment: Do every server support gettext? This is gonna be an open-source so it should work on most servers.

Comment: If not, you could expand on my answer :). It works similar to how gettext does. You would just need to add another function. The good thing about gettext, is that there is a way (at least in Python) to extract every string that needs to be translated, but you could write a script to do that I think.